# Pytorch update hyper-parameter using current loss, RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am defining my own loss function, and my own loss function has a hyper-parameter **Lambda**. For example, if the prediction is **y**, then I define the loss function as **Loss = Lambda * y**. I want to update my **Lambda** at some iteration using the current round's **Loss**. For example, at some specific iteration, I want my **Lambda** to be updated as **Lambda = Lambda + Loss**, then it returns the error of

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

Specifically, my naive code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

batch_size, input, output = 10, 3, 3
model = nn.Linear(input, output)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
lam = torch.from_numpy(np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]))
lam.requires_grad = False

for i in range(10):
    x = torch.rand(batch_size, input)
    output = model(x)
    loss = torch.sum(lam*output)
    if i == 5:
        lam = lam + torch.clone(loss)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(loss)
```

I had the feeling that the error was caused by using **Loss** to update my **Lambda**. So I used the code `torch.clone(loss)`, hoping not to influence `loss`, it didn't help. Does anyone know how to fix the problem? Some explanation about why this error occurs would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly take a look [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-trying-to-backward-through-the-graph-a-second-time-but-the-buffers-have-already-been-freed-specify-retain-graph-true-when-calling-backward-the-first-time/6795/2).
There's explanation why the error occurs in your code.

`To reduce memory usage, during the .backward() call, all the intermediary results are deleted when they are not needed anymore. Hence if you try to call .backward() again, the intermediary results don’t exist and the backward pass cannot be performed (and you get the error you see).`

So if you want to fix the problem, you can easily solve it by adding a parameter:

```
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
```

or

```
lam = lam + torch.Tensor([loss.item()])
```

Hopefully it helps! ;)

Comment: I looked at the post before, and I feel like it is a different question than mine. I understand that backward() deletes the intermediary results. But my code was computing the loss first at that round, though the result of loss might be deleted from the last round's backward(), isn't it computed again in the new round?

Comment: Also, I didn't want to use retain_grph=True, because it's too much cost on memory. This piece of code was just a naive model I used to ask questions, my real code is much larger than this. Why the second solution works `lam = lam + torch.Tensor([loss.item()])` again?